# How to solve "Expression expected" and "cannot infer argument" errors?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, arguments, expression

can anyone help me to solve this "Expression expected" and "cannot infer argument"  errors in the codes below? The "Expression expected" error occurs in the line `public void viewData () {`. While the "cannot infer argument" errors occur in the line `adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItem);`

```
public class profile extends Fragment {
DatabaseHelper dbHelper;
ArrayList<String> listItem;
ArrayAdapter adapter;
ListView userlist;


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_profile, container, false);
    dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());
    userlist = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.user_list);
    listItem = new ArrayList<>();
    dbHelper.viewData();


    public void viewData () {
        Cursor cursor = dbHelper.viewData();

        if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No Data Show!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                listItem.add(cursor.getString(6));
                listItem.add(cursor.getString(0));
                listItem.add(cursor.getString(1));
                listItem.add(cursor.getString(2));
                listItem.add(cursor.getString(3));
                listItem.add(cursor.getString(4));
                listItem.add(cursor.getString(5));

            }
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItem);
            userlist.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the method I added in DatabaseHelper.java to display my data that is stored in SQlite database.

```
public Cursor viewData(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String query = "Select * from "+TABLE_NAME;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);

    return cursor;
}
```

Comment: The "Expression expected" error happens because you put a method inside another method. The "cannot infer arguments" error happens because it's trying to infer the type parameters but it's too complex or you're passing the wrong type. Trying specifying the type arguments explicitly maybe?

Comment: `viewData` method should be outside `onCreateView` or just remove `viewData` method declaration and keep its body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have a method inside another method. You can however declare the ViewData method on its own and then call it from the onCreateView method if you need it.

Comment: hello, can you show me how can I do it? I'm new to android studio. I don't really understand your explanation. Thanks

Comment: The viewData method can remain the same but you just have to move it outside the OnCreateView method. Then you can replace the code you moved from OnCreateView method by calling it using viewData();